# Publish MATLAB class documentation to HTML

Tags: html, matlab, documentation

I am creating a MATLAB package using object-oriented programming. I have documented my classes according to a [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-help-for-classes.html) from MathWorks website. This standard of documentation, however, only works for `doc` and `help` commands, but not when I use `publish`. For example, properties, which have their description written in front of their declaration, don't have said declaration exported to HTML. There is no list of properties or methods at the beginning of the file, so that users can quickly skip to those. Lastly, documentation has to be read directly from the comments in the code, instead of being parsed to HTML.

When I try to add some HTML documentation inside my classes to `publish` them, the code also appears on `doc` and `help`, which is an undesired behavior. **Is there a way to create class documentation so that properties and methods can be published to the Web?** I've had experience with doc generators like Sphinx (Python) and Doxygen (many languages), in which the descriptions of classes, methods and properties are parsed to HTML so they can be published in places like [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) or [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com) so I am curious to know if MATLAB has something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [MTOC++](https://github.com/mdrohmann/mtocpp) which uses Doxygen, therefore produces the standard Doxygen HTML documentation.

I have used it already to generate source code documentation for Matlab project containing standard Matlab functions, old class definitions with @ notation and classes defined by `classdef` mixed, and it worked after some tailoring.

> This somewhat larger project allows to create documentation for MatLab
>   files and classes (including packages) using a doxygen filter named
>   mtoc++. Moreover, a tool/class named MatlabDocMaker allows to create
>   the documentation from within MatLab. For Windows, Mac and Unix!

You can find it also on [Mathworks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33826-mdrohmann-mtocpp) and you can find the documentation [here](http://www.ians.uni-stuttgart.de/MoRePaS/software/mtocpp/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

One widely-used way to provide HTML documentation for MATLAB functions/class is the [M2HTML](http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/m2html/) project. It will automatically generate HTML documentation complete with dependency graphs, source code, and syntax highlighting.